# case_when when there are factors

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyr

I am trying to combine treatment allocations for patients who completed two different randomisation forms. I can simulate some example data here:

```
data <- data.frame(id = 1:100,
                   trt_a = factor(c(sample(0:1, 50, TRUE), rep(NA, 50))),
                   trt_b = factor(c(sample(0:1, 50, TRUE), rep(NA, 50))),
                   trt_ab = factor(c(rep(NA, 50), sample(c("a", "b", "ab", "neither"), 50, TRUE))))
```

Is there any way of creating a new column with the same factor levels as `trt_ab`? Half the patients had choice of either `trt_a` or `trt_b`, and the other half had choice `trt_ab`. I want to use some sort of `case_when` statement to generate a new column with the actual treatment choices:

```
data %>%
  mutate(trt = case_when(trt_a == 0 & trt_b == 0 ~ "neither",
                         trt_a == 1 & trt_b == 0 ~ "a",
                         trt_a == 0 & trt_b == 1 ~ "b",
                         trt_a == 1 & trt_b == 1 ~ "ab",
                         !is.na(trt_ab) ~ trt_ab))
```

However, when any of the columns are factors, I get the following error:

```
Error in `mutate()`:
! Problem while computing `trt = case_when(...)`.
Caused by error in `` names(message) <- `*vtmp*` ``:
! 'names' attribute [1] must be the same length as the vector [0]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
data %>%
  mutate(trt = case_when(trt_a == 0 & trt_b == 0 ~ "neither",
                         trt_a == 1 & trt_b == 0 ~ "a",
                         trt_a == 0 & trt_b == 1 ~ "b",
                         trt_a == 1 & trt_b == 1 ~ "ab",
                         !is.na(trt_ab) ~ trt_ab)) %>% head
```

-output

```
 id trt_a trt_b trt_ab     trt
1  1     0     0   <NA> neither
2  2     0     0   <NA> neither
3  3     1     1   <NA>      ab
4  4     1     1   <NA>      ab
5  5     0     1   <NA>       b
6  6     1     1   <NA>      ab
```

Comment: That's strange - I've just restarted R and get the same error with a clean session. I'm on R-4.2.1 with dplyr-1.0.10. I could probably botch a fix bit I can't figure out why this isn't working when it should.

Comment: @jackahall i use the dev version of dplyr with R 4.2.2

Comment: Dev version of dplyr has fixed it :)